# SQL: How to show the WHERE IN and WHERE NOT IN in the same line?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, notin

Good morning masters.

Basically i want to show 3 tables. But i have some condition:

- show table `perangkat`,`jenis_perangkat`,`pasang` but only show the data with ID that has been saved on table `sedia` (those 3 tables above have the same ID named `kd_jp` and has been saved on `sedia`) AND DON'T SHOW the data with ID that has been saved on `pasang`.

After run the code above, i got syntax error. It is working until this :

```
SELECT  `perangkat`.`kd_jp`,  `perangkat`.`no_seri`,  `perangkat`.`status`,  
        `jenis_perangkat`.`nm_jp`,  `jenis_perangkat`.`merk_jp`
FROM`perangkat`
INNER JOIN `jenis_perangkat` 
ON `jenis_perangkat`.`kd_jp` = `perangkat`.`kd_jp` 
WHERE perangkat.kd_jp IN (select sedia.kd_jp from sedia)
```

BUT it's not working when i add the NOT IN : `and where perangkat.kd_jp not in (select pasang.kd_jp from pasang);`

So here is the Query that got Syntax Error:

```
SELECT  `perangkat`.`kd_jp`,  `perangkat`.`no_seri`,  `perangkat`.`status`,  
        `jenis_perangkat`.`nm_jp`,  `jenis_perangkat`.`merk_jp`
FROM`perangkat`
INNER JOIN `jenis_perangkat` 
ON `jenis_perangkat`.`kd_jp` = `perangkat`.`kd_jp` 
WHERE perangkat.kd_jp IN (select sedia.kd_jp from sedia) 
  AND where perangkat.kd_jp not in (select pasang.kd_jp from pasang);
```

Comment: you cannot have more than one `where` in a single query. you can have multiple CONDITIONS in that where, but only `where` can exist in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one `WHERE` clause. Change `WHERE ... AND WHERE ...` to `WHERE ... AND ...`:

```
SELECT `perangkat`.`kd_jp`, `perangkat`.`no_seri`, `perangkat`.`status`,
  `jenis_perangkat`.`nm_jp`, `jenis_perangkat`.`merk_jp` 
FROM `perangkat`
INNER JOIN `jenis_perangkat`
  ON `jenis_perangkat`.`kd_jp` = `perangkat`.`kd_jp`
WHERE perangkat.kd_jp IN (SELECT sedia.kd_jp FROM sedia)
  AND perangkat.kd_jp NOT IN (SELECT pasang.kd_jp FROM pasang);
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use **and where**:

```
and where perangkat.kd_jp not in (select pasang.kd_jp from pasang);
```

just use **and**:

```
and where perangkat.kd_jp not in (select pasang.kd_jp from pasang);
```

SQL sintaxe select sintaxe is

```
select * from [table] WHERE ... AND ... AND ... OR ...
```

So

```
SELECT  `perangkat`.`kd_jp`,  `perangkat`.`no_seri`,  `perangkat`.`status`,  `jenis_perangkat`.`nm_jp`,  `jenis_perangkat`.`merk_jp`FROM`perangkat`INNER JOIN `jenis_perangkat` ON `jenis_perangkat`.`kd_jp` = `perangkat`.`kd_jp` where perangkat.kd_jp in (select sedia.kd_jp from sedia) and perangkat.kd_jp not in (select pasang.kd_jp from pasang);
```

**UPDATE**

A better solution is use **EXISTS** instead of **IN** and **NOT IN**

```
SELECT a.kd_jp, a.no_seri, a.status, b.nm_jp, b.merk_jp 
FROM perangkat a 
INNER JOIN jenis_perangkat b  ON b.kd_jp = a.kd_jp 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT c.kd_jp FROM sedia c WHERE c.kd_jp = a.kd_jp) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT c.kd_jp FROM pasang c WHERE c.kd_jp = a.kd_jp);
```